# Merging documents while storing all ids in an array

Tags: mongodb

So in mongodb 3.2 (for reasons, we can't upgrade yet) I have a bunch of documents in this structure:

```js
// Document 1
{
    "id": "record-1",
    "childItems": [
        "child-1",
        "child-2"
    ],
    "specLookup":[
        {
            "specId": "spec-1"
        },
        {
            "specId": "spec-2"
        }
    ]    
},

// Document 2
{
    "id": "record-2",
    "childItems": [
        "child-3"
    ],
    "specLookup":[
        {
            "specId": "spec-3"
        }
    ]    
}
```

I need an aggregation query that will merge and manipulate all these records into one document, while maintaining all individual ids in a new array. So based on the two documents above I'd end up with this:

```js
{
        "ids": ["record-1", "record-2"],
        "childItems": [
            "child-1",
            "child-2",
            "child-3"
        ],
        "specIds":[
            "spec-1"
            "spec-2",
            "spec-3"
        ]    
    }
```

How can I do this? Cheers!

Comment: How are you filtering/grouping the existing documents? Just all of them in the collection end up in a single document? Are there other fields that need to be considered/preserved while grouping?

Comment: At the moment they are not being filtered or grouped in a manner like this. Yes there are other fields at the root of each document and within each object of the specLookup array.

I just realised I should clarify that when I said manipulate, I don't need the original documents to end up like this in the db. I just need this single object coming out of the query in a different structure to the source documents

Comment: Great. I'm pretty sure what you need is pretty straightforward - $group on _id:null, use $push to generate "ids", and $concatArrays for "childItems" and "specIds". Trailing $project stage to remove the _id if you don't want it (_id:0). Pretty sure all of that works on 3.2

Comment: Hey, thanks very much. Do you have an example of the syntax for $concatArrays? When trying to do it within the $group stage mongodb 3.2 complains that it's an unknown $group operator. Also all examples for concatArrays show it concatenating different arrays, rather than values for the same array across multiple documents. NeNaD's example below works using reduce in latest, but I don't have that operator available in 3.2

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

- `$group` - to group all the documents add collect all the `ids`, `childItems` and `specLookup`.
- `$reduce` with `$concatArrays` - to get the data in the format you want.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "ids": {
        "$addToSet": "$id"
      },
      "childItems": {
        "$addToSet": "$childItems"
      },
      "specLookup": {
        "$addToSet": "$specLookup.specId"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "childItems": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$childItems",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "specLookup": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$specLookup",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1ID_tmy1cN9)

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for the response! That's great thank you. The $set operator isn't available in 3.2 so I have to use $project instead. However, the current issue I have now is 3.2 throws and "Invalid operator $reduce" error. What would be the alternative I should use instead of $reduce for 3.2?

This is what I currently have based on your example:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/kQ0UT2Qjurp